# Facebook Sharing plugin doesn’t detect the specified post URL

Tags: facebook, url, post, plugins, sharing

I use Facebook share button to share my article (Title, description and image) on Facebook using Open Graph Meta and other default Meta 
And my articles are echoed in post.php page like (mywebsite.com/post.php?id=post_id) which contents differ through post_id.
Well, while sharing a post on fb, facing some problems.

1: fb share doesn't detect the image belonging to the article/current post that is shared. (Thought the image URL in my Open Graph Meta is correct) and after sharing it on Facebook the link doesn’t redirect to the exact URL (mywebsite.com/post.php?id=post_id).

2: the fb share button is in my post.php page which shares different posts but sharing is counted same for all posts.
The FB share button has got an attribute (data-href="url-to-share") which my one is (data-href="`<?php echo'post.php?id=post_id';?>`").
Anyone know what and where is wrong with my code/URL addressing?

Comment: Have you debugged the URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your meta tags shows correct data then must be fb issue. I faced similar problem before.
 Try debug your url in the FB debugger( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ ). It helps.

Fb haven't grab your updated data because they have their own time/interval to grab new data from the website(if im not mistaken). Using the debugger u'll see how the share will look like and show missing details if any.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: oh sorry! i'll do that next time. :)